# Error compiling opa file

Tags: opa

I'm new to Opa (and complied languages) - normally develop web apps with Python.

I'm following the intro tutorial at http://doc.opalang.org/index.html#_introducing_opa but my hello_chat.opa file won't compile when I run "opa hello_chat.opa".  I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdbm_compat
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
>   Error: Error during linking
>   make: *** [native] Error 2
>   error during ocaml compilation -- the command was :
>   make --makefile=Makefile -W Makefile -j 7 native -s

I'm on Debian 6.0.2.  I installed opa per the instructions at "2.1.2. Ubuntu Linux, Debian Linux" in the intro tutorial linked above.

Lua is not installed.  However, liblua5.1-0 is installed (if that is even relevant).

Answer (score 2):

Seems we have a new dependency for Opa : `libgdbm-dev`

Try installng it ;)

For your information (from the opa owasp list) :

> Concerning libgdbm-dev, it's a rather new dependency and we are not
>   sure we want to keep it. At least we will make it an official
>   dependency for future packages.

Answer (score 1):

I think this dependency is no longer necessary in the latest stable build. Which version do you use (`opa --version`) ? Check http://opalang.org and download `Build 569`

Comment: This did the trick, too.  I was using build 520 and installing libgdbm-dev got it working.  After that, I removed libgdbm-dev and installed build 569 and it worked beautifully.  Thanks much!